# What is the ideal age to go to university for a degree?

Tags: mathematics, career-path, bachelor

as the title suggests, I am looking for any advice, thoughts, or opinions on what is an ideal age to be going to university. It would be for a degree first, then after however, a masters, then (hopefully), a phd.

I am looking to study mathematics, though, I am 16 soon to be 17,  currently homeschooled, but I self teach. I was hoping that I could use 4 years to deeply self study mathematics before going to university, In order to learn everything that I would need for first entering a mathematics degree.

4 years would leave me at around 20 or 21 years old. To me, that feels a bit old? And so I ask what would be the most ideal age for entering. I would guess most answers to be 18 or 19, however I don’t think I could cover all content needed for entering a mathematics degree by that age.

As well, would I have a lower chance of admittance being slightly older than the average student entering at, say 18 or 19 years old? I would be looking to enter into university(particularly queens), on mathematical knowledge alone.

If it is of any help, I am in the UK.

Sorry if this is not a well structured question, I am new to Academia stack exchange.

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on the country - many universities allow students to take courses based on education, motivation and don’t limit age as some pensioners have proved.

Comment: Why do you think you need 4 years to study mathematics before starting your degree? Are you currently deficient in mathematics? In which case, why do you want to study it at degree level?

Comment: Well, up until about a year ago, I had no interest in mathematics, I was only interested In computers and computer science. Then one day I made the connection that everything is related to mathematics, particularly in computer science. Since that day I have been trying to learn mathematics from the ground up as my knowledge was quite sparse prior. I also really enjoy learning and doing mathematics now. I am presuming to learn calculus and some basic linear algebra, it will take around 4 years of self study. Though, maybe not? I am just keeping my goals/estimates realistic.

Comment: Don't worry about your age. I know people who went to uni at 16, and others (like me) who went to uni at 20. Age is not something that will be on the mind of those who may accept your application. You may need to do some form of standardized tests before being admitted (such as SAT's) so they can check your skill. Beware though, that Linear algebra won't be taught until you're *in* uni, nor will any substantial calculus. If you finish ~90% of KhanAcademy's base curriculum, you'll be more than set. So you probably won't need 4 years.

Comment: Do you meet the entry requirements for a degree in mathematics? If so, then there's no need to spend four years studying mathematics, you can apply immediately. Otherwise, invest the necessary time to meet those requirements and then apply.

Comment: You mentioned that you're also interested in computer science. You might want to consider studying a computer science degree, with an emphasis on the underlying mathematics. Or you might want to study a computer science and mathematics degree.

Comment: Well, its sort of complicated. Currently I am and have been for a few years, doing a computer science degree online through the open university. However, I have not done any math related modules in it, only computer science things. So, I am now wanting to go to a real physical university to study mathematics. I would then complete a masters and PhD in computer science after the mathematics degree.

Comment: "The best time to start was 10 years ago, the second best time is today"

Comment: At least in the US, you probably wouldn't "enter a mathematics degree" right away, you would probably take at least a year, maybe two to actually be in the degree, taking the advanced courses. Maybe that'll put your mind at ease a little bit.

Comment: The question isn't really appropriate for this site, since it's about undergraduate admissions. Having said that, you should either go directly into a maths degree, or if you don't meet the requirements, look at doing a **foundation year** first. Self-study for four years is a very bad idea, and is unlikely to improve your chance of admission much.

Comment: The ideal age will be the normal age for beginning undergraduates in the UK, about 18. University is a social experience as well as an academic one. Practicing living and working with people your own age is especially important after home schooling and Open University.

Comment: Take one step at a time. Don't skip steps, in case you're exceptional they might pass faster. Age..? 20-ish is better, but I hope 50 is also fine :-)